# String value to be inserted in a date datatype mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, datetime

I want to insert current date into a database in the field `cur_dt` having datatype date.

```
 string curr_dat= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Can i insert `curr_dat` which is a string variable into a column `cur_dt` having datatype as date?

If not than how can i do it? How to define a date variable.I want to also insert current time in the a column `cur_tm` having datatype time.

Please help me to understand how to insert the date and time into the database.

Comment: `INSERT INTO TABLE(Date_Column)VALUES(CURDATE())` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

Comment: i think this is a good example of "not a real question".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write SQL like

```
INSERT INTO foo SET bar='<date here>'
```

or similar, you can use both parameters or just String.Format to put the date there as a STring.

Additionally, if you want to put the current Date/Time there, why not just use

```
INSERT INTO foo SET bar=now() -- if column type is datetime
INSERT INTO foo SET bar=CURDATE() -- if column type is date
```

and have the database set in the correct date in the correct form

Answer (score 1):

read mysql date/time functions here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert curr_dat variable to DateTime before assigning it to cur_dt column. You can also create a new DateTime value is following way

```
DateTime curDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,0,0,0);
```

and assign the value to cur_dt column.

Answer (score 0):

str_to_date(string_data, format)

STR_TO_DATE('Dec/15/2011', '%M/%d/%Y'); => 2011-12-15